# Proper way to save Transfer Learning model in Keras

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, keras

I have trained a constitutional net using transfer learning from ResNet50 in keras as given below.

```
base_model = applications.ResNet50(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(333, 333, 3))

## set model architechture
x = base_model.output
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
x = Dense(1024, activation='relu')(x) 
x = Dense(256, activation='relu')(x) 
predictions = Dense(y_train.shape[1], activation='softmax')(x) 
model = Model(input=base_model.input, output=predictions)

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizers.SGD(lr=1e-4, momentum=0.9),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.summary()
```

After training the model as given below I want to save the model.

```
history = model.fit_generator(
    train_datagen.flow(x_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size),
    steps_per_epoch=600,
    epochs=epochs,
    callbacks=callbacks_list
)
```

I can't use save_model() function from models of keras as model is of type Model here. I used save() function to save the model. But later when i loaded the model and validated the model it behaved like a untrained model. I think the weights were not saved. What was wrong.? How to save this model properly.?

Comment: What happens when you use `save_model()`?

Comment: it says Model dont have that function.

Comment: What version of keras are you using?

Comment: Keras version is 2.0.6

Comment: save_model is not a member function of any model class, it is a function in package keras.models.

Comment: could you provide your code with loading model after using `model.save`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As per [Keras official docs](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/),
If you only need to save the architecture of a model you can use

```
model_json = model.to_json()
with open("model_arch.json", "w") as json_file:
    json_file.write(model_json)
```

To save weights

```
model.save_weights("my_model_weights.h5")
```

You can later load the json file and use

```
from keras.models import model_from_json
model = model_from_json(json_string)
```

And similarly, for weights you can use

```
model.load_weights('my_model_weights.h5')
```

I am using the same approach and this works perfectly well.

Comment: I will try using this approach. I was knowing this method but haven't tried it as save_model() and load_model() was working fine till now.

Comment: I like to know what really is happening when is use the save() function. Don't the weights get saved.?

Comment: The `model.save()` function is exactly the same as `save_model()`. It's just a wrapper of `save_model()`.

Comment: I have saved and loaded the model as json. But I can't continue training. It still behaves as an untrained model.

Comment: @SreeramTP Have you loaded the weights after loading json file.

Comment: Yes, i have loaded the weights.

Comment: Try compiling the model after loading weights.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what happens with my models, but I've never been able to use `save_model()` and `load_model()`, there is always an error associated. But these functions exist.

What I usually do is to save and load weights (it's enough for using the model, but may cause a little problem for further training, as the "optimizer" state was not saved, but it was never a big problem, soon a new optimizer finds its way)

```
model.save_weights(fileName)
model.load_weights(fileName)
```

Another option us using numpy for saving - this one never failed:

```
np.save(fileName,model.get_weights())
model.set_weights(np.load(fileName))
```

For this to work, just create your model again (keep the code you use to create it) and set its weights.

Comment: load_model() and save_model() was working fine for me when using normal  nets with Sequential, LSTMs etc. I am facing this problem only with transfer learning.

Comment: I had also tried saving and loading just the weights keeping the model architecture same. Then also the model behaves untrained.

Comment: Have you set the `trainable=False` to all of the `base_model` layers before compiling?

Comment: Then your training is changing the resnet model. It's possible that it loses quality greatly at first.

Comment: So what is the best way to save and reuse the model.? Saving to json.?

Comment: Either my answer or the other one will work. But at any time you need to "train", you have to set all resnet layers to `trainable=False` before compiling. (Unless you really want to retrain the resnet model).

Comment: Ok. I will try both approches. What if i want to continue training.? Say I trained for n epochs and saved the model and later loaded it and i want to train the model for m more epochs. Can it be done.?

Comment: Yes, it's possible.

Comment: I will try and tell how it went. Thanks

Comment: I have saved and loaded the model as json. But I can't continue training. It still behaves as an untrained model.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155017/discussion-between-sreeram-tp-and-daniel-moller).